# Sum of powers for lists of tuples

Tags: python

My assignment is to create a function to sum the powers of tuples.

```
    def sumOfPowers(tups, primes):
        x = 0;
        for i in range (1, len(primes) + 1):
            x += pow(tups, i);
        return x;
```

So far I have this.

tups - list of one or more tuples, primes - list of one or more primes

It doesn't work because the inputs are tuples and not single integers. How could I fix this to make it work for lists?

[/edit]
Sample output:

```
sumOfPowers([(2,3), (5,6)], [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]) == 2**3 + 5**6
True

sumOfPowers([(2,10**1000000 + 1), (-2,10**1000000 + 1), (3,3)], primes)
27
```

Sum of powers of [(2,4),(3,5),(-6,3)] is 2^4 + 3^5 + (−6)^3

**The purpose of the prime is to perform the computation of a^k1 + ... a^kn modulo every prime in the list entered. (aka perform the sum computation specified by each input modulo each of the primes in the second input list, then solve using the chinese remainder theorem )

Primes list used in the example input:

```
     15481619,15481633,15481657,15481663,15481727,15481733,15481769,15481787 
    ,15481793,15481801,15481819,15481859,15481871,15481897,15481901,15481933 
    ,15481981,15481993,15481997,15482011,15482023,15482029,15482119,15482123 
    ,15482149,15482153,15482161,15482167,15482177,15482219,15482231,15482263 
    ,15482309,15482323,15482329,15482333,15482347,15482371,15482377,15482387 
    ,15482419,15482431,15482437,15482447,15482449,15482459,15482477,15482479 
    ,15482531,15482567,15482569,15482573,15482581,15482627,15482633,15482639 
    ,15482669,15482681,15482683,15482711,15482729,15482743,15482771,15482773 
    ,15482783,15482807,15482809,15482827,15482851,15482861,15482893,15482911 
    ,15482917,15482923,15482941,15482947,15482977,15482993,15483023,15483029 
    ,15483067,15483077,15483079,15483089,15483101,15483103,15483121,15483151 
    ,15483161,15483211,15483253,15483317,15483331,15483337,15483343,15483359 
    ,15483383,15483409,15483449,15483491,15483493,15483511,15483521,15483553 
    ,15483557,15483571,15483581,15483619,15483631,15483641,15483653,15483659 
    ,15483683,15483697,15483701,15483703,15483707,15483731,15483737,15483749 
    ,15483799,15483817,15483829,15483833,15483857,15483869,15483907,15483971 
    ,15483977,15483983,15483989,15483997,15484033,15484039,15484061,15484087 
    ,15484099,15484123,15484141,15484153,15484187,15484199,15484201,15484211 
    ,15484219,15484223,15484243,15484247,15484279,15484333,15484363,15484387 
    ,15484393,15484409,15484421,15484453,15484457,15484459,15484471,15484489 
    ,15484517,15484519,15484549,15484559,15484591,15484627,15484631,15484643 
    ,15484661,15484697,15484709,15484723,15484769,15484771,15484783,15484817 
    ,15484823,15484873,15484877,15484879,15484901,15484919,15484939,15484951 
    ,15484961,15484999,15485039,15485053,15485059,15485077,15485083,15485143 
    ,15485161,15485179,15485191,15485221,15485243,15485251,15485257,15485273 
    ,15485287,15485291,15485293,15485299,15485311,15485321,15485339,15485341 
    ,15485357,15485363,15485383,15485389,15485401,15485411,15485429,15485441 
    ,15485447,15485471,15485473,15485497,15485537,15485539,15485543,15485549 
    ,15485557,15485567,15485581,15485609,15485611,15485621,15485651,15485653 
    ,15485669,15485677,15485689,15485711,15485737,15485747,15485761,15485773 
    ,15485783,15485801,15485807,15485837,15485843,15485849,15485857,15485863
```

Comment: Just a tip - Python has no need of semicolons.

Comment: How are the tuples and primes related?

Comment: What is a power of a tuple?

Comment: Can you give us sample input and expected output at all?

Comment: There is no exact relationship between the tuples and primes.

Comment: What's the point of the `primes` list?

Comment: It appears that you want to take two lists and do some calculation on them, but it isn't quite clear what you want.  the algorithm you express calculates the sum of all powers from 1 - len(primes)+1.  But suspect you want to raise each element of tuple to each power listed in primes.

Comment: Is the point to find out the sum of all powers for the base for each power, and then add the sum of any other prime powers as well? So 2^17 is 2^3 + 2^5 + 2^7 ... 2^17?

Comment: The primes list is just some random list of numbers that the user inputs.

Comment: @user2827356 But why is it passed to the function at all? What are you supposed to *do* with it?

Comment: It's related to Euler's theorem.

Comment: How is it related? You never use that parameter. Are you trying to calculate totients?

Comment: The purpose of the prime is to perform the computation of a^k1 + ... a^kn modulo every prime in the list entered.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure if I understand you correctly, but maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
from functools import reduce

def sumOfPowersModuloPrimes (tups, primes):
    return [reduce(lambda x, y: (x + y) % p, (pow (b, e, p) for b, e in tups), 0) for p in primes]
```

You shouldn't run into any memory issues as your (intermediate) values never exceed `max(primes)`. If your resulting list is too large, then return a generator and work with it instead of a list.

Comment: Fails for OP’s test cases.

Comment: @poke For `sumOfPowers([(2,3), (5,6)], [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29])` it yields `[0, 3, 2, 2, 7, 10, 15, 16, 2]`. Where is the fail? What is the expected result? Compare the result with `for p in [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]: print ( (2**3 + 5**6) % p)`.

Comment: That one should magically equal to `2**3 + 5**6`. Just like the other call yields just `27`. I can’t tell you how it is supposed to do that.

Comment: It's not even clear from the OP if it should return 27, since in his examples he's completely ignoring the primes, but implies that the primes should be used for modulo arithmethic.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring `primes`, since they don't appear to be used for anything:

```
def sumOfPowers(tups, primes):
    return sum( pow(x,y) for x,y in tups)
```

Is it possible that you are supposed to compute the sum modulo one or more of the prime numbers? Something like

```
2**3 + 5**2 mod 3 = 8 + 25 mod 3 = 33 mod 3 = 0
```

(where `a+b mod c` means to take the remainder of the sum `a+b` after dividing by `c`).

---

One guess at how multiple primes would be used is to use the product of the primes as the
divisor.

```
def sumOfPower(tups, primes):
    # There are better ways to compute this product. Loop
    # is for explanatory purposes only.
    c = 1
    for p in primes:
        p *= c
    return sum( pow(x,y,c) for x,y in tups)
```

(I also seem to remember that `a mod pq == (a mod p) mod q` if `p` and `q` are both primes, but I could be mistaken.)

---

Another is to return one sum for each prime:

```
def sumOfPower(tups, primes):
    return [ sum( pow(x,y,c) for x,y in tups ) for c in primes ]
```

Comment: Aren't you in the last line missing a modulo? Like: `[ sum( pow(x,y,c) for x,y in tups ) % c for c in primes ]` The sum can exceed the current prime.

Comment: Sadly, yes. I could either compute the remainder for the entire sum, or abandon `sum` and use a loop to compute the remainder after each individual addition. It's not clear which would be faster (keeping the numbers small vs. reducing the number of divisions), so benchmarking would be required.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumOfPowers (powerPairs, unusedPrimesParameter):
    sum = 0
    for base, exponent in powerPairs:
        sum += base ** exponent
    return sum
```

Or short:

```
def sumOfPowers (powerPairs, unusedPrimesParameter):
    return sum(base ** exponent for base, exponent in powerPairs)
```

---

> perform the sum computation specified by each input modulo each of the primes in the second input list

That’s a completely different thing. However, you still haven’t really explained what your function is supposed to do and how it should work. Given that you mentioned Euler's theorem and the Chinese remainder theorem, I guess there is a lot more to it than you actually made us believe. You probably want to solve the exponentiations by using Euler's theorem to reduce those large powers. I’m not willing to further guess what is going on though; this seems to involve a non-trivial math problem you should solve on the paper first.

```
def sumOfPowers (powerPairs, primes):
    for prime in primes:
        sum = 0
        for base, exponent in powerPairs:
            sum += pow(base, exponent, prime)

        # do something with the sum here
        # Chinese remainder theorem?
    return something
```

Comment: I run out of memory doing some of the tests, is there a way to make this more efficient?

Comment: @user2827356 Are you using py2 or py3? Py3 is a lot more memory friendly as it uses generators in many places where py2 uses lists, and hence saves the cost of the allocation of that list.

Comment: The only real memory this function uses is `sum`; are you generating a number *that* big? That would take a loooong time unless you have some very large exponents.

Comment: I am using p3. I have to modify the function to be able to take inputs that are extremely large

Comment: What is extremely large? The length of the first parameter or the integers contained in the tuples?

Comment: If the exponents are extremely large

Comment: You can’t really optimize a calculation like `2 ^ ((10 ^ 1000000) + 1)` in a good way… In this case, you could probably check if there are two element `(x, e)` and `(-x, e)` in the list (i.e. same exponent, different sign) in which case the result for that particular pair would be zero. But in general, for other combinations? Impossible. I still wonder if the primes list does have a point after all though…

Comment: Primes list - perform the sum computation specified by each input modulo each of the primes in the second input list, then solve using the chinese remainder theorem

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but pow() can take a third parameter to do the work modulo a prime, which won't run out of memory.